# can i know how many pages are in an Epub file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, epub

I would like to know if there is a way to know how many pages is there in an Epub file so I can split it to RAR files if the number of pages exceeds 100 pages. I am using Node JS.

EDIT

what I want to do is check if an epub file has more than 100 pages in it. if this is the case I split it in 4 rar files that contain just the html and the image of each 25 page. I don't want to create another Epub files I just want to extract to content of the original Epub file and split it between the rar files.

Comment: epub does not have pages, it is a task of a displaying device to decide the pages sizes (heavily depends on the screen size and resolution).

Comment: You can count the number of content (XHTML) files. But in any case, what do you mean by "split it to RAR files"? What's the problem you're trying to solve? Splitting an EPUB is going to be difficult to impossible to do automatically.

Comment: what I want to do is check if an epub file has more than 100 pages in it. if this is the case I split it in 4 rar files that contain just the html and the image of each 25 page. I don't want to create another Epub files I just want to extract to content of the original Epub file and split it between the rar files.

Comment: You cannot count pages. As an earlier commenter already mentioned, EPUBs do not have pages; pages are artifacts of the device and reading process. An EPUB might have 1000 pages on an iPhone and 100 on some other device. You'll have to find some other metric. Once you've done this, and split the files, what are you going to do exactly with the RAR files? Why are you wanting to do that, as I already asked?

Comment: after getting my epubs I need to be able to render the html's and images in order. its like extracting the epub than generates mini parts to be rendered in the browser independently from the epub but still respecting the order of pages.

Comment: Well, you can't render anything unless your mini-parts also have all the CSS and JS and fonts and images, and you won't know which are needed unless you parse and analyze all the XHTML pages, so this is a very big job, and you still haven't explained what the problem is you're trying to solve.

Comment: this is what i am doing. and i guess we are drifting from the subject of the post . anyway thank you for your help.